# When I reset STATIC_URL to Amazon S3/CloudFront for my production app, Django Admin no longer finds its CSS stylesheet

Tags: django, django-admin

How do I resolve? I don't want to push a copy of Django Admin's CSS to my static files unless I have to. Is that my only option or ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you move your application to production, in addition to setting `DEBUG = False` in your `settings.py`, you also have to run `collectstatic` and then upload these files to your webserver.

`collectstatic` will put all the static files that are required for all installed applications, including the django.contrib apps (like the django admin), into the folder you specified as `STATIC_ROOT`. You should then copy the entire contents of this folder to wherever your `STATIC_URL` is pointing to.

If you don't do the above, your stylesheets and other assets will not appear correctly.

As you are using S3, the excellent [`django-extensions`](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) package provides a `sync_s3` command that will handle synchronizing your bucket for you.

Starting from django 1.6, there is an official [list of things you should do](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/) before you are ready to deploy; so if you are on the current version of django make sure you visit that page.  It is also pointed to in the comments in `settings.py`.

Comment: Thanks. I will walk through this info and implement.

Answer (score 1):

in Django 1.3 you could set `STATIC_URL` to the S3 URL and `ADMIN_PREFIX` to your local server, creating a webserver alias that serves the files
(in Apache for example: `Alias /static/admin/ /absolute/path/to/static/admin/`)

but AFAIK this is **deprecated** in Django 1.4 and **not possible** with Django >= 1.5, since they always will point to `{{STATIC_URL}}admin/`.

but i don't understand, why wouldn't you upload your admin static!? i strongly suggest to `colletstatic` all your media to S3 :)

(i don't know if i understood you question correctly, i'll update the answer if not)

Comment: Thanks. I'll get started on django-extensions.