# How can I get STATIC_URL into my 500.html template so my page renders correctly with my css

Tags: django

According to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19701 Django does not automatically include STATIC_URL as context for this template so the page is rendered without my css. How can I include it? The docs linked in the article above didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

the answer by *mlavin* in the ticket you referenced contains the solution:

load the staticfiles app in the template and then use the [`static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/#with-a-template-tag) template tag, which does not depend on the `RequestContext`:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static "images/hi.jpg" %}" />
```

Comment: I didn't post the ticket, I referenced it. And your suggestion doesn't help to my knowledge. My css file, included in my 500.html template by {{ extends base.html }} and referenced as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}app.css">` needs a value for {{STATIC_URL}}.

Comment: I think the answers (including one from you - thanks!) to my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467666/when-i-reset-static-url-to-amazon-s3-cloudfront-for-my-production-app-django-ad will address this for me.

Comment: i suggest you to use the 'static' template tag instead of STATIC URL, it's also cleaner and more legible ;)